# How to use a variable outside the using statement?

Tags: c#, list, variables, scope, using

How can I use a variable outside the using statement ?

I have this code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["batch"].ConnectionString))
{
    var size = FileBusinessLogic.LoadBatchAvgFileSizes(connection);  // size is a list
}
```

I need to use the "var size"outside of the using, but I don't know how. And how can I get the second column of the list(size) ?

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: You will need to declare size outside of the using statement (with an initial value) and then assign to it within the using statement.

e.g. 
List<int> size = null;
using (...)
{
   size = FileBusinessLogic.LoadBatchAvgFileSizes(connection);
}

Comment: aah that already helps a lot , but how to do that ? because size is a list wich contains an column of  int ( for the filesize) and acolumn of string for the filename

Comment: @CasperLimburg  "how can I get the second column of list(size)?" This is totally unrelated to the variable being inside or outside the `using` statement.

Comment: What kind of objects are there in size list?

Comment: thnx it already works fine. now i'm only giffering out how to use a linq statement but i will use a new topic for that

Answer (score 6):

Braces is compose their own scope. All variables are visible only in declared scope and inner scopes.

You just need to declare your variable outside using scope:

```
int size = 0; // or declare expected type
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["batch"].ConnectionString))
{
    size = FileBusinessLogic.LoadBatchAvgFileSizes(connection); // size is a list
}

// now you have access to your variable outside the using scope.
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it a method:

```
private static List<int> GetSize()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["batch"].ConnectionString))
    {
        return FileBusinessLogic.LoadBatchAvgFileSizes(connection);  // size is a list
    }
}

...

var size = GetSize();
```

Answer (score 0):

you will be able to use it this way,

```
var size = new List<t>() ;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["batch"].ConnectionString))
{

 size = FileBusinessLogic.LoadBatchAvgFileSizes(connection);  

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an action,

```
    Action<List<int>> handleSize = size =>
    {
        // you can do what you wanna do with size here.
        Console.WriteLine(size);
    };

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["batch"].ConnectionString))
    {
        var size = FileBusinessLogic.LoadBatchAvgFileSizes(connection);  // size is a list
        handleSize(size);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `C# 8.0` you can use [using declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using) and then you don't need to
move the variable declaration out of the scope.

```
using SqlConnection connection =
    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["batch"].ConnectionString)

var size = FileBusinessLogic.LoadBatchAvgFileSizes(connection);  // size is a list

// size can be used here...
```